# How to Send a List in jQuery to WebApi

Tags: jquery, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I have my WebApi which returns a list and also take a List of Key Value pair

```
public List<myCustomers> GetCustomerDetails(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> searchCriteria)
       {

}
```

I am using ajax to call the service as :

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://MYSERVER/VCCSearchRestService/api/VCCSearch/GetCustomerDetails? 
 searchCriteria=WhatShoudIPassHere',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'MyJSONPCallback',
                type: 'GET',
                // specify the callback name if you're hard-coding it
                success: function (data) {
                    // we make a successful JSONP call!
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it with a Post Method

```
public List<myCustomers> PostCustomerDetails(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> searchCriteria)
{
{
```

Ajax Call

```
 var keyvaluepair = [{"key1","value1"},{"key2","value2"}];
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://MYSERVER/VCCSearchRestService/api/VCCSearch/PostCustomerDetails',
    dataType: 'json',
    jsonpCallback: 'MyJSONPCallback',
    data: JSON.stringify(keyvaluepair);  // pass list here
    type: 'POST',
    // specify the callback name if you're hard-coding it
    success: function (data) {
        // we make a successful JSONP call!
    }
});
```

Comment: Why does it have to be a  Post Method?